# Weird error occured while using JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I was trying to make a tic tac toe game with javafx but suddenly after added an `if` the program stopped working properly and if [`if(chiediConferma)`] I remove said error the compiler gives me error while there weren't any error in the script.

Now let me explain how the program worls first througth a confirm box the program ask the player if they want play tic tac toe then if the player chooses `"si"`(`"yes"` in italian) the they window with the game appears, if they pick `"no"` the program simply ends. When I added said if the game window appeared blank and when I click on it the cursor turns in to the loading icon and it is like this until an `"X stopped working"` popup appears, do you have an idea on what is the problem?

(sorry for broken grammar and english)

```
 import java.util.Random;
    import javafx.application.*;
    import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
    import javafx.event.*;
    import javafx.scene.*;
    import javafx.stage.*;
    import javafx.scene.control.*;
    import javafx.scene.layout.*;
    import javafx.geometry.*;
    import javafx.collections.*;

    public class ProgettoVisualeAngeloDenatalle4INF extends Application  {
    static int vittoriaOpareggio;
    static int cVittoria;
    static boolean chiediConferma;
    static boolean conferma;
    static boolean premuto00;
    static boolean premuto01;
    static boolean premuto02;
    static boolean premuto10;
    static boolean premuto11;
    static boolean premuto12;
    static boolean premuto20;
    static boolean premuto21;
    static boolean premuto22;


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args); // setta il programma come una javaFx Application

}

@Override
public void start(Stage window) throws Exception {
    window.setTitle("Tris");

    cVittoria = 0;
    vittoriaOpareggio = 0;
    chiediConferma = true;
    premuto00 = true;
    premuto01 = true;
    premuto02 = true;
    premuto10 = true;
    premuto11 = true;
    premuto12 = true;
    premuto20 = true;
    premuto21 = true;
    premuto22 = true;

    do {
        if (chiediConferma) {
            if (vittoriaOpareggio == 3) {
                conferma = Menu.PartiMenu("Pareggio", "Vuoi giocare ancora?");
                chiediConferma = false;
                vittoriaOpareggio = 0;
            } else if (vittoriaOpareggio == 1) {
                conferma = Menu.PartiMenu("Vittoria", "Vuoi giocare ancora?");
                chiediConferma = false;
                vittoriaOpareggio = 0;
            } else if (vittoriaOpareggio == 2) {
                conferma = Menu.PartiMenu("Sconfitta", "Vuoi giocare ancora?");
                chiediConferma = false;
                vittoriaOpareggio = 0;
            } else {
                conferma = Menu.PartiMenu("", "Vuoi giocare a tris");
                chiediConferma = false;
            }

        }

        if (conferma) {
            final int DIM = 3;
            int matriceTris[][] = new int[DIM][DIM];

            Button bott00 = new Button();
            Button bott01 = new Button();
            Button bott02 = new Button();
            Button bott10 = new Button();
            Button bott11 = new Button();
            Button bott12 = new Button();
            Button bott20 = new Button();
            Button bott21 = new Button();
            Button bott22 = new Button();

            TextField text00 = new TextField("[ ]");
            TextField text01 = new TextField("[ ]");
            TextField text02 = new TextField("[ ]");
            TextField text10 = new TextField("[ ]");
            TextField text11 = new TextField("[ ]");
            TextField text12 = new TextField("[ ]");
            TextField text20 = new TextField("[ ]");
            TextField text21 = new TextField("[ ]");
            TextField text22 = new TextField("[ ]");

            GridPane tabella = new GridPane();

            tabella.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
            tabella.setVgap(10);
            tabella.setHgap(5);

            tabella.setConstraints(text00, 0, 0);
            tabella.setConstraints(text01, 0, 2);
            tabella.setConstraints(text02, 0, 4);
            tabella.setConstraints(text10, 1, 0);
            tabella.setConstraints(text11, 1, 2);
            tabella.setConstraints(text12, 1, 4);
            tabella.setConstraints(text20, 2, 0);
            tabella.setConstraints(text21, 2, 2);
            tabella.setConstraints(text22, 2, 4);

            tabella.setConstraints(bott00, 0, 1);
            tabella.setConstraints(bott01, 0, 3);
            tabella.setConstraints(bott02, 0, 5);
            tabella.setConstraints(bott10, 1, 1);
            tabella.setConstraints(bott11, 1, 3);
            tabella.setConstraints(bott12, 1, 5);
            tabella.setConstraints(bott20, 2, 1);
            tabella.setConstraints(bott21, 2, 3);
            tabella.setConstraints(bott22, 2, 5);

            tabella.getChildren().addAll(text00, text01, text02, text10, text11, text12, text20, text21, text22, bott00, bott01, bott02, bott10, bott11, bott12, bott20, bott21, bott22);

            if (premuto00) {
                bott00.setOnAction(e -> {
                    text00.setText("[X]");
                    matriceTris[0][0] = 1;

                    premuto00 = false;
                });
            }

            if (premuto01) {
                bott01.setOnAction(e -> {
                    text01.setText("[X]");
                    matriceTris[0][1] = 1;

                    premuto01 = false;
                });
            }

            if (premuto02) {
                bott02.setOnAction(e -> {
                    text02.setText("[X]");
                    matriceTris[0][2] = 1;

                    premuto02 = false;
                });
            }

            if (premuto10) {
                bott10.setOnAction(e -> {
                    text10.setText("[X]");
                    matriceTris[1][0] = 1;

                    premuto10 = false;
                });
            }

            if (premuto11) {
                bott11.setOnAction(e -> {
                    text11.setText("[X]");
                    matriceTris[1][1] = 1;

                    premuto11 = false;
                });
            }

            if (premuto12) {
                bott00.setOnAction(e -> {
                    text12.setText("[X]");
                    matriceTris[1][2] = 1;

                    premuto12 = false;
                });
            }

            if (premuto20) {
                bott20.setOnAction(e -> {
                    text20.setText("[X]");
                    matriceTris[2][0] = 1;

                    premuto20 = false;
                });
            }

            if (premuto21) {
                bott00.setOnAction(e -> {
                    text21.setText("[X]");
                    matriceTris[2][1] = 1;

                    premuto00 = false;
                });
            }

            if (premuto22) {
                bott22.setOnAction(e -> {
                    text22.setText("[X]");
                    matriceTris[2][2] = 1;

                    premuto22 = false;
                });
            }

            Scene scenaTris = new Scene(tabella, 1200, 800);
            window.setScene(scenaTris);
            window.show();
        } else {
            vittoriaOpareggio = 4;
        }
    } while (vittoriaOpareggio == 0);

}

public static int controlloVittoria(int mat[][]) {
    return 0;
}
```

here is the menu class:

```
public class Menu 


public static boolean PartiMenu(String titolo, String messaggio){

    Stage menu = new Stage();

    menu.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);    

    Label Messaggio = new Label();
    Messaggio.setText(messaggio);

    Button si = new Button("Si");
    Button no = new Button("No");
    si.setOnAction(e -> {
       scelta = true;
       menu.close();
    });
    no.setOnAction(e -> {
       scelta = false;
       menu.close();
    });

    GridPane selezione = new GridPane();
    selezione.setPadding(new Insets(10,10,10,10));
    selezione.setVgap(10);
    selezione.setHgap(10);

    selezione.setConstraints(Messaggio, 1,0);
    selezione.setConstraints(si, 0,1);
    selezione.setConstraints(no, 2,1);

    selezione.getChildren().addAll(Messaggio, si, no);

    Scene SceneMenu = new Scene(selezione, 1000, 600);
    menu.setTitle(titolo);

    menu.setScene(SceneMenu);

    menu.showAndWait();
    return scelta;
}
```

}

here is the error screen:

```
    run:
Exception in Application constructor
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to construct Application instance: class progetto.visuale.angelo.denatalle.pkg4inf.ProgettoVisualeAngeloDenatalle4INF
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:907)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$156(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:819)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$176(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$174(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$175(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$149(WinApplication.java:191)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - illegal start of type
    at progetto.visuale.angelo.denatalle.pkg4inf.ProgettoVisualeAngeloDenatalle4INF.<init>(ProgettoVisualeAngeloDenatalle4INF.java:244)
    ... 13 more
Exception running application progetto.visuale.angelo.denatalle.pkg4inf.ProgettoVisualeAngeloDenatalle4INF
C:\Users\Enzo\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 3 seconds)
```

Comment: Could you include the code for `Menu.PartiMenu`? Perhaps it's blocking the UI thread?

Comment: Added the menu class

Comment: Any solution to the problem?

Comment: Can you include the full error message, and format the missing parts of the code? You can get information on [how to format here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

Comment: Thanks, i've added the error and the code that i was not able to add

Comment: so have you found any solution?

Comment: Have you found anything?